# No connectivity to the dind container on OpenShift to build the docker images

Tags: docker, jenkins, openshift, jenkins-plugins, docker-in-docker

I'm using an OpenShift Cluster provisioned on Azure (UPI) and running Jenkins instance to build Containers using `dind`. I have installed this [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/) and it corectly Spin up the job container and everything works except the internet and dns inside the `dind` container.

Here is the sample pipeline I use

```
podTemplate(yaml: '''
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: docker-socket
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: docker-daemon
        image: docker:19.03.1-dind
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: docker-socket
          mountPath: /var/run
      - name: docker
        image: docker:19.03.1
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        command:
        - sleep
        args:
        - 99d
        volumeMounts:
        - name: docker-socket
          mountPath: /var/run
''') {
  node(POD_LABEL) {
    stage('Get the project') {
      git 'https://github.com/repo/Dockerfile-repo.git'
      container('docker') {
        stage('Build a docker image') {
          sh 'docker version && docker ps'
          sh 'docker image build -t repo/image-name:version .'
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

The strange thing is I have some commands in the Dockerfile to update and install using apt-get. Those are not working due to the connectivity. Giving the below erros

```
 ---> Running in f8eb2b386fc9
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package ca-certificates is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package wget
E: Unable to locate package iproute2
E: Unable to locate package vim
E: Unable to locate package unzip
E: Unable to locate package curl
```

Anybody has similar experience or faced this issue before? If so please assist me to fix it with your valuable thoughts.

Please note that I need to fix this and alternative solutions are not required.

Appreciate your valuable thoughts and suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: What have you already done/researched/debug to try understand why your container/pod does not have access to internet (firewal rules, proxy, openshift miss-configuration, etc.....)? Note that this question is probably more suited for https://serverfault.com

Comment: Actually, I need to highlight that the container spin up by the jenkins has the internet access. For example if I add a sleep in the build step and login to the container and execute `apt update` perfectly works, but in the docker file it is not. I will post it there as well. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Please don't post it there *as well*. Either leave it here or delete it to transfer it to the other site. In other words, don't cross-post the same question on different stack exchange sites, choose the most appropriate one. Thanks.

Comment: hmmm... okay. I'll leave it here. then, anyway no luck with my issue yet.